# Typeahead not working with Pyramid_deform and Bootstrap 3

Tags: python, twitter-bootstrap-3, migration, typeahead.js, deform

I got the task of migrating a project to Bootstrap 3, Now we are using [deform](http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/deform/en/latest/), and [deform_Bootstrap](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/deform_bootstrap/0.2.9)(also we are using [pyramid_deform](http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid-deform/en/latest/))

At first I got `TypeError: $(...).typeahead is not a function`, Then I upgraded all the packages, i.e `[QueryUI](http://api.jqueryui.com/), and [typeahead.js](https://github.com/twitter/typeahead.js/) to the latest versions.

Now it does not give me an error, but its not working either(not Auto-Completing).

Here is my code:

```
class Consignment(colander.MappingSchema):
    agent = colander.SchemaNode(
        colander.String(),
        validator=agent_validator,
        widget=AutocompleteInputWidget(
            size=60,
            # style="width: 250px",
            min_length=3,
            values="/agents/list.json"
            ))
```

And then somewhere else There is the following

```
def render_form(context, request):
    schema = Consignment()
    if not context or context.__is_new__:
        c_form = Form(schema, buttons=('create consignment',))
    return c_form.render()
```

I am using the latest version of [deform](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/deform/2.0a2) and I have included the Bootstrap 3 libraries.

Is this a bug in [Deform](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/deform/2.0a2)?
How can I get past this obstacle? Any help would be apreciated.

Comment: Is your URL invoked?  What does it return, if so?

Comment: If I go to the url directly it returns a json file...
I have also tried request.route_url("route.to.path"), but `request` returns None...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem...
I had to manually import/include the [typeahead.css](https://github.com/Pylons/deform/blob/master/deform/static/css/typeahead.css) and [typeahead.js](https://github.com/Pylons/deform/blob/master/deform/static/scripts/typeahead.min.js) from the Deform library, I also had to include [deform.js](https://github.com/Pylons/deform/blob/master/deform/static/scripts/deform.js)...

Thanks @ChrisMcDonough for all your help... I really appreciate it.